# How to add README file to jar created from netbeans

Tags: java, jar, netbeans-7

I am able to create a jar file through netbeans and then run it. Does anyone know how to include a README file in the jar so that anyone who extracts the jar can see the readme file?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of "[Netbeans and external configuration files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301283/netbeans-and-external-configuration-files)" and/or "[How can I include a folder into the dist JAR as part of the build process using Netbeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497019/how-can-i-include-a-folder-into-the-dist-jar-as-part-of-the-build-process-using)", if you are using Ant as your build system.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a zip tool of your choice to add the extra file.

Comment: This is what I am doing. But is there a way to actually add the file to the jar? As opposed to the directory containing the jar?

Comment: So it's more a betbeans configue question. Sorry I am an eclipse guy.