# Netbeans/java adding external config files

Tags: java, file, netbeans, external, config

Based on this topic: [Netbeans and external configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301283/netbeans-and-external-configuration-files)

I assume that what I want to do this is possible. But the answer is not really working for me.
The code is use know is from the last answer:

```
 <target name="-pre-jar">
    <echo>Copying resources files to build directory...</echo>
    <mkdir dir="${dist.jar.dir}/resources"/>
    <copy todir="${dist.jar.dir}/resources">
        <fileset dir="resources" includes="**"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

But this just creates a dir named: ${dist.jar.dir} with my resources folder and files in it at the same location of my src,dist,build,nbproject folder. But I want it to be in dist, so my dist has, the jar, lib,webfiles and resources.

Thanks for any help and clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved it, so to copy a file, I placed the file in in a folder within src named resources with in there my file.

And then the following code does the trick:

```
 <target name="-post-jar">
    <copy file="${src.dir}/resources/filename.extension" flatten="true" todir="${dist.dir}/resources" />
</target>
```

Okay, for some reason my jar isn't being builded/updated any more if I use this in my build file..Anyone any clues?

solved needs to be "-post-jfx-jar" for jfx projects

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy all the contents of a specific directory to the `\dist` directory of the build you can do the following:

```
<target name="-pre-init">
    <!-- Create a resource directory property -->
    <property name="src.res.dir" value="${basedir}/res" />
</target>

<target name="-pre-jar">
    <!-- Copy external resources folder -->
    <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}\inside\res\dir">
        <fileset dir="${src.res.dir}\inside\res\dir">
            <include name="**/*" />
        </fileset>
    <copy>
</target>
```

This will copy the contents of a folder called `\inside\res\dir` inside of your projects `$\res` directory. I use this technique to include an application icon in the distribution.

You should then be able to access these resources from inside your application with something like the following:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("inside/res/dir/file.ext")
```

Comment: I have been trying this but it doesn't seem to work, I corrected the /copy error it gave but other stuff I didn't change. So I placed a directory res/inside/res/dir and in dir my document where I have my build en dist and nbproject dirs. But when I build I just doesn't do anything. So I was thinking it should be just inside/res/dir but then he says the can't find / doesn't exist and build failed. I don't know if I'm just doing something wrong or there slipped a small error in your solution. Thanks for any help